# why is it returning -8 instead of -4..?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#define foo(x,y) x/y +x     
int main()
    {
        int i=-6,j=3;
        printf("%d",foo(i+j,3));
    }
```

PROBLEM;
this code is giving answering -8

is not it return -4 mathematically ..
please explain ..help

Comment: Try compiling your source code with `gcc -E` to see how `i+j` is substituted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foo(x,y)` is defined as `x/y +x`, so `foo(i+j,3)` expands to `i+j/3 +i+j`. Since `/` has higher precedence than `+`, this is equivalent to `i + (j / 3) + i + j`, *not* to `(i + j) / 3 + i + j` as you presumably intended.

The best fix in this case is to not use a macro, but rather, to just write a normal function:

```
int foo(int x, int y) {
    return x / y + x;
}
```

If, for whatever reason, that's not an option, then you need to add some parentheses:

```
#define foo(x,y) ((x) / (y) + (x))
```

. . . but even this will give weird results if the `x` has side-effects, because the `x` gets expanded twice, so those side-effects will happen twice. (And in some cases that will result in undefined behavior.)

Comment: Adding on, if you want to see what your macro expands to, you can use the `-E` option (i.e. preprocessor arg) in gcc as:
`gcc -E myfile.c -o preproc.c`

Comment: When replacing a macro with a function, it is often best to declare the function `static inline`, as this more closely aligns with what a macro does: Provide some inline code visible only in the current translation unit. So `int foo(int x, int y)` could be `static inline int foo(int x, int y)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's -8 of the way macros work in C. At compile time, all macros in your code are replaced verbatim with the macro definition.

So, in your example, all occurrences of `foo(x+y)` are replaced with `x/y +x` which when applied to the printf goes from

```c
printf("%d",foo(i+j,3));
```

to

```c
printf("%d",i+j/3 + i+j);
```

which, when substituted with the values of i and j give the following

```c
printf("%d",-6+3/3 + -6+3);
```

And thus, -8 is printed.